# Can I get UIScreen points from GMSMarker points?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

I have included google map view in my project and successfully showing marker on it. Google map is only providing pop animation of marker. i want drop animation for the markers.

I have successfully implemented radius animation zoom in and zoom out but need marker drop animation.

So my idea is like if I get exact point of marker into UIScreen then I will drop pin from top of my screen that will make effect of drop animation.

finally i got drop animation from below code but there is one problem that I didn't get perfect points from mapview to show drop animation.

```
//Drop pin
    func setMarker(latitude : Double, longitude : Double, isForJobLocation : Bool = false){

        let point = mapView.projection.point(for: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude:  longitude))
        let viewPoints = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.convert(point, from: mapView)

        print(viewPoints)

        self.showAnimatation(xPosition: viewPoints.x, yPosition: viewPoints.y) {

            let marker1 = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude:  longitude))
            marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "mapLoadingPin")
            marker1.map = self.mapView
        }

    }

    func showAnimatation(xPosition : CGFloat, yPosition : CGFloat, completion : @escaping (() -> ())){

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition - 100, width: 44, height: 44))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "mapLoadingPin")
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            imageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (true) in
            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
            completion()
        }
    }
```

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code:

1. You convert the CGPoint from your mapView to the coordinate system of the keyWindow. But then you are adding your imageView to your view using the CGPoint calculated for your window.
2. You do not take the imageViews size into account. I guess your marker image should be placed horizontally centered above the point on the map. (but this depends on the design of your marker image)

---

The following changes should fix your problem:

- Convert the GMSMarkers origin to the coordinate system of the parentView of your imageView. Replace

  `let viewPoints = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.convert(point, from: mapView)`

  with

  `let viewPoints = self.view.convert(point, from: mapView)`
- Take the imageViews size into account. The origin of your imageView (**after** animation) should be (xPosition - imageView.width/2, yPosition - imageView.height). In your example replace

  `let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition - 100, width: 44, height: 44))`

  with

  `let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition - 22, y: yPosition - 44 - 100, width: 44, height: 44))`

---

If that shouldn't fix your problem help us to help you by providing a screenshot showing the misplaced imageViews.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and your problem is using the `origin.y` for your imageView frame.

> A point that specifies the coordinates of the rectangle’s origin.

According to Apple document, origin sort of represents the minX and minY of your CGRect. So, you should be refactoring your position as such:

```
imageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition - imageView.bounds.height
```